# How to set ipv6 address for an interface from a C program

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ioctl

I am writing a program that needs to set the ip address of an interface and set it `UP` and `RUNNING`. I could do it for ipv4 addresses using `ioctl(SIOCSIFADDR)`, but same thing for ipv6 address gives an error.

Following is the code snippet:

```
 329     memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
 330     strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, in.dev.device, IFNAMSIZ);
 331 
 332     /* we need a socket descriptor for ioctl(). Cant use tun descriptor */
 333     s = socket(in.over_n, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
 334     /* Now check if socket we got is ok */
 335     if (s < 0)
 336         raise_error("socket()");
 337         
 338 
 339 
 340     switch (in.over_n) {
 341     
 342     case AF_INET:   memset(&addr4, 0, sizeof(addr4));
 343                     addr4.sin_family = AF_INET;
 344                     /* Convert ip to network binary */
 345                     stat = inet_pton(addr4.sin_family, in.dev.ip_addr, &addr4.sin_addr);
 346                     ifr.ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr4;
 347                     break;
 348                     
 349     case AF_INET6:  memset(&addr6, 0, sizeof(addr6));
 350                     addr6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
 351                     /* Convert ip to network binary */
 352                     stat = inet_pton(addr6.sin6_family, in.dev.ip_addr, &addr6.sin6_addr);
 353                     ifr.ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr6.sin6_addr;
 354                     break; 
 355     default:        raise_error("invalid network prot");
 356     }               
 357                     
 358     /* Check if conversion happened properly */
 359     if (stat == 0)
 360         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid ip");
 361     if (stat == -1)
 362         raise_error("inet_pton() - invalid family");
 363         
 364     if (stat != 1)
 365         raise_error("inet_pton()");
 366         
 367     char dum[BUFF_SIZE];
 368     if (inet_ntop(in.over_n, &ifr.ifr_addr, dum, BUFF_SIZE) != NULL)
 369         printf("name = %s, ip = %s\n",ifr.ifr_name,dum);
 370     
 371     /* Set ip */
 372     if (ioctl(s, SIOCSIFADDR, (caddr_t) &ifr) == -1) 
 373         raise_error("ioctl() - SIOCSIFADDR");
```

This works fine for ipv4 addresses, but ipv6 addresses give me error:

```
name = tun9, ip = aaaa::bbbb
ioctl() - SIOCSIFADDR: Invalid argument
```

If I change line 353 to

```
 353                     ifr.ifr_addr = *(struct sockaddr *) &addr6;
```

Then the error changes to

```
name = tun9, ip = a00::aaaa:0:0:0
ioctl() - SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
```

I noticed that `struct ifreq` has a member `struct sockaddr` which I think is smaller than `struct sockaddr_in6` but is as large as `sockaddr_in`. I was wondering if that is the problem and `struct ifreq` can not hold the ipv6 address. If that is true, what do we use for `ioctl()` involving ipv6 addresses?

The input ip address I am trying to set is `aaaa::bbbb`, `in.over_n` is `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.

Any help will be much appreciated. Please let me know if I need to post more code, outputs etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240724/assign-ipv6-address-using-ioctl)

Comment: Thanks @ScottyBauer, that worked for ip address but is not working for mask. I will need to debug some more, but I could not understand what exactly the code was doing. There is no explanation on that answer.
Can you tell me what is exactly being done there?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, when I get some time ill add comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you can point me to any guide or documents on `ioctl()`, `ifreq` and related stuff, that will be great. I tried searching on the web but could not find a definitive source.

Answer (score 0):

For IPv6, you should use the rtnetlink API instead. This is the API used by tools like ip, and probably ifconfig uses it too in modern versions.

rtnetlink has advantage that it supports multiple addresses per device, and can provide more information as it is a bit more dynamic, and do many fancy things.

But rtnetlink API can also be tricky to get working initially, since it requires a little selections of structures to populated and parsed correctly, including some strange combinations of members that needs the correct sizeof() filled in.