# Adding multiple ipv6 addresses to a single interface using ioctl

Tags: c, linux, ipv6

I am trying to port my application to ipv6 and my current code brings up alias IP addresses dynamically as shown:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:35:68:21:5B
          inet addr:192.168.1.245  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:35ff:fe68:215b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:278885750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68117973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:68976932662 (64.2 GiB)  TX bytes:39384521280 (36.6 GiB)
          Interrupt:169

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:35:68:21:5B
          inet addr:192.168.1.246  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:169

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6060179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6060179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2366257047 (2.2 GiB)  TX bytes:2366257047 (2.2 GiB)
```

eth0:1 will be added dynamically by the application. It uses ioctl to do this. I want to do the same for IPV6 address. I tried this [Assign ipv6 address using ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240724/assign-ipv6-address-using-ioctl). But the example code is adding IPV6 address to the existing interface eth0 instead of eth0:1 or eth0:2 even if I specify the interface name as eth0:1. Can anyone please help since I am new to IPV6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. In IPv4 each interface could have only one address. To add more addresses you had to create 'fake' interfaces like `eth0:1`. IPv6 always has multiple addresses per interface so work-arounds like `eth0:1` are not used for IPv6.

Comment: Hello, how can I remove only that particular IP address from the interface without deactivating the entire interface? Currently I am using ioctl with get and set flags which is bringing down the entire interface(which is not desirable)

Comment: Take a look at http://mailman.icsi.berkeley.edu/pipermail/xorp-hackers/2003-October/000010.html

Comment: Hi, I have one more doubt. I am trying to bind the IPV6 global address, newly added to the interface to an IPV6 UDP socket, but it is failing with error:Cannot assign requested address. Please help!!

Comment: Please check this link >> [ifconfig](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TNxjylQTRQgzZ1XZ06O7k0mqgFWSrwn0qMJGw-H-6E4/edit). I wanted to bind to IPV6 addresses marked in red, but the bind is throwing error.

Comment: Those are IPv4 addresses in IPv6 notation. Why don't you use IPv4 sockets for that?

Comment: I tried using IPV4 socket and bind is successful, but recvfrom is not receiving any data from client. And when I am trying to send data from server to client I am getting **`recvfrom(): Address family not supported by protocol`**. Please check [my code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bohYhA0Wa6j2pZbBIDlArus0DSfe43fqOvFZEgF1rNk/edit)

Comment: I should have said: why are you putting IPv6-mapped-IPv4 addresses on an interface instead of real IPv4 addresses? Using IPv6 sockets should work both for real IPv6 addresses and IPv6-mapped-IPv4 addresses, but I wouldn't be surprised if the kernel gets confused when you add IPv6-mapped-IPv4 addresses to an interface.

Comment: I was trying to do code changes for porting IPv4 code to IPv6. Currently I have been given a test machine that has only IPv4 addresses. So I was trying to test with IPv6-mapped-IPv4 addresses. I get your point!! I'll try to get a machine that has IPv6 addresses. Thanks!!

Comment: I used an IPv6 address instead of IPv6-mapped-IPv4 address and it worked. Thanks!! :)

Comment: If you want IPv6 addresses for local testing you can use ULA addresses. You can also get a free IPv6 tunnel from tunnelbroker.net or sixxs.net

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Deactivation, bind, everything is working fine now :D