# Why sysctl disables ipv6 for new created interface?

Tags: c, linux, sysctl

I'm creating interface with IPv6 address using this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338398/2317204

On ubuntu (x86_64) everything works fine, however on angstrom linux I see the failure of ioctl setting SIOCSIFADDR flag. So, I can create interface, but without IPv6 address.
The problem is that for my new interface sysctl is net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=1.

I changes 'all' and 'default' sysctl lines with 'disable_ipv6' to 0, but it doesn't help me.

Also, I tryed with disabled and enabled avahi-daemon.
If I create interface, then manually set sysctl disable_ipv6=0 for this interface, my code adds IPv6 address without problems.

So, my questions are:

1. Why sysctl sets disable_ipv6=1 automatically for just created
   interface?
2. Is it possible to change sysctl config programatically?

UPDATE: I'm really sorry, I got a wrong information about the remote PC I'm working with. It's not Linux Phantom, it's Angstrom Linux. I suppose I can google solution myself and post it here later.

Comment: You probably need to ask somewhere where you can get support specific to Phantom OS. I've never heard of it before, and SO has no tag for it, leading me to think you'll have a hard time finding someone knowledgeable on SO. It's also mildly off-topic since it doesn't seem to be a programming question but a system configuration question.

Comment: @R. It's the same linux, with the same system functions. If my question looks like offtopic, I can make it shorter: how to change sysctl.conf in linux programatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "same Linux"? Same kernel (version and configuration), or what?

Comment: Also, you could ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ maybe (not sure if this is too technical for that, but probably it's ok).

Comment: @hyde thank you. Actually, "same linux" means "same system functions". If it's possible to change sysctl.conf programatically on ubuntu, I can use the same solution for linux phantom.

Comment: You should also add kernel versions and distro versions to the question.

Comment: If it doesn't happen on Ubuntu, it's probably something broken that your distro has patched or configured. It wasn't clear from your question that "Phantom OS" was actually Linux and not something providing just a similar API.